# How to create a live wallpaper for android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper, renderscript

I know there's a lot of information about creating a live wallpaper with renderscript, but I thought I read somewhere that this way of doing things would be deprecated.  I don't know if I just imagined that or not, but I don't want to start learning something that won't be supported in the future.

Any good resources or helpful links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see that it is deprecated from `API 16` so that is `Android 4.1`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/RenderScriptGL.html

so in that case have a look at this.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/m194NFf_ZqA

You can use `OpenGL ES 2.0`

http://www.learnopengles.com/how-to-use-opengl-es-2-in-an-android-live-wallpaper/

Comment: Yes I know that it's deprecated, that's why I asked for current resources.

Comment: So in that case you can use `OpenGL ES 2.0` http://www.learnopengles.com/how-to-use-opengl-es-2-in-an-android-live-wallpaper/

Comment: @travis did you saw that opengl es 2.0 link?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of examples available for Live Wallpapers.

http://www.emirac.net/android/index0.html

http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/12605-android-live-wallpaper-tutorial.html

[Simplest example of an Android live wallpaper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728641/simplest-example-of-an-android-live-wallpaper)

Comment: These seem to be for 2.1, I'm looking for something that takes into account performance, such as renderscript.  However renderscript is deprecated, which is what I've mentioned in the question...